# Neo4j relationship property - array of values vs duplicate relationship

Tags: neo4j, nosql

Lets say I have two nodes of type  (: City).
Whats the better approach to store relationahip when some user walks from one city to another?. Please note that for this case we want to save day value (NOT daytime) and name of user.

Lets say that the same user walks between same two cities on 5 different day

What I have been thinking about is:

1) there will be a new relationahip each time when user walks from City(a) to City(b). However, that would create 5 different relationships with pretty much the same content (same user name in this case), only `day` value will be different.

2) there will be one relationship for each `user` and single data type(long) for property `day` will be replaced with an array of long values.

What do you think is better approach? Either create multiple relationships even if they share most of its properties, or create a one relationship with those shared properties and put variable ones into an array.
If you have any other ideas or suggestions please write them :)

Thanks
c.

Comment: What kind of queries are you planning on making on this data? For example, will you need to look up what cities people walked between on certain days? Which cities a person has walked between within some time span? Which people have walked between the same two cities, and on which days? How many people have walked between some set of cities within a given span?

Comment: @InverseFalcon Thanks for reply! The main query will be: Which people have walked between the same two cities for specific days range. So, for example and I have City(a) City(b) and I want to know who have walked between these two cities on day(1 - 3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the spirit of the graphs, you can:

- have a node for city
- have a node for user
- have a node for a fact of walking

[image]

Comment: Hi @stdob-- 
but what if `Christian` have walked between Paris and Bergen 5 times ? Should graph have 5 different nodes, or node with number `3` will contains array of values, when (on which days) Cristian walked between these two cities ?

Comment: @creck Yes, five different nodes for each fact of walking.

Comment: Thank you, thats what I wanted to know :)